# SQL error : a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I'm stuck on a (probably stupid) SQL error, I don't know why this gives me an error :

```
INSERT INTO np_postpic 
            (id_postpic, postpic_name, postpic_url, postpic_height, postpic_width) 
    VALUES (NULL, 1, 1, 1, 1);
```

> 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`netsplosiv`.`np_postpic`, CONSTRAINT `np_postpic_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_postpic`) REFERENCES `np_news` (`id_postpic`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Relation is ok, and I try several combination of `"Foreign key" (CASCADE, Null, RESTRICT / NO ACTION...)`

[image: Database Overlook]

[image: 1rst Table]

[image: 2nd Table]

[image]

Comment: You have to have an `np_news` row with `np_news.id_postpic` set to what you are setting the `np_postpic` rows `id_postpic` column to. So in this case NULL in this case

Comment: I believe you put the foreign key constraint on the wrong table.

Comment: I do think Bill has a good point there

Comment: But it was automatically added when I made the Relationship in the PHPMyAdmin Designer.

Comment: I ask myself maybe I did click on the wrong one 1rst but PHP Mysql only make me do it 1 way so I suppose it was the good one

Answer (score 0):

You can't update a column in a parent table (if you have a constraint on it) that has a foreign key linked to it as this will result in orphaned row.

Comment: Parent table ? But for me parent table is "np_news", not "np_postpic"

Comment: Are you sure? as in the images you show the parent table is np_postpic. As in the np_news table why would you have 2 primary key columns and np_postpic no primary key and just 1 foreign key?

Comment: But I always did that before and it always worked : 
https://pasteboard.co/eScV82iUZu1x.jpg
(this is the project I did for school and it worked flawlessly)

Comment: Ok I compared, : the Contraint Key isn't in the good table I think. Strange. PHP Mysql didn't make it as it was supposed to be